# How do I retrieve data after <strong> tag from HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to retrieve some portion of data from HTML code. Here it is :

```
<article class="article-detail-description">
<h1 class="page-heading">
Przedterminowe wybory parlamentarne w Europie Środkowej i Wschodniej. Model normatywny, przyczyny i konsekwencje
<br /><small>Early parliamentary elections in Central and Eastern Europe. Normative model, reasons and consequences</small>
</h1>

<div>
<strong>Author(s): </strong>Andrzej Antoszewski<br />
<strong>Subject(s): </strong>Politics / Political Sciences<br />
<strong>Published by: </strong>Łódzkie Towarzystwo Naukowe<br/>
<strong>Keywords: </strong>East-Central Europe; early election; parliament; normative model<br/>
</div>
```

I can get all the information from `article-additional-info` class to which the above-mentioned piece of code belong. I can do it by using `document.getElementsByClassName("article-additional-info")[0].innerText`.

How do get individual information such as: `Author(s):`?
I'd like to avoid using RegEx.

Comment: does `article-additional-info` contains this div? or div's classname is `article-additional-info`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
// get all span ccontent
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('article-additional-info')[0].getElementsByTagName('strong')).forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e.textContent);
});

// get all elements including text node
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('article-additional-info')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].childNodes).forEach(function(e) {
  e.textContent.trim() && console.log(e.textContent.trim());
});

// or Array.from(document.querySelector('.article-additional-info div').childNodes)
```

```html
<div class="article-additional-info">
  <div>
    <strong>Author(s): </strong>Andrzej Antoszewski
    <br />
    <strong>Subject(s): </strong>Politics / Political Sciences
    <br />
    <strong>Published by: </strong>Łódzkie Towarzystwo Naukowe
    <br/>
    <strong>Keywords: </strong>East-Central Europe; early election; parliament; normative model
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```